# Laravel: Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\RuntimeException : The process has been signaled with signal "6"

Tags: php, laravel

Whenever I am running
`"php artisan make:migration create_team_table --create=team"`
to create migration file then I am getting this output:

```
Created Migration: 2018_05_09_115803_create_team_table

Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\RuntimeException  : The process has been signaled with signal "6".

/home/webdev/public_html/vendor/symfony/process/Process.php: 392


       if ($this->processInformation['signaled'] && $this->processInformation['termsig'] !== $this->latestSignal) {
           throw new RuntimeException(sprintf('The process has been signaled with signal "%s".', $this->processInformation['termsig']));
       }

       return $this->exitcode;
   }
```

Exception trace:

```
1   Symfony\Component\Process\Process::wait()
      /home/webdev/public_html/vendor/symfony/process/Process.php : 201

  2   Symfony\Component\Process\Process::run()
      /home/webdev/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Composer.php : 50
```

Please use the argument -v to see more details.

Can anyone tell me why am I getting that runtime Exception?

Comment: try `php artisan make:migration create_teams_table --create=teams`

Comment: Already checked. I have tried with all the possible names (eg. team, players, countries). And I am getting this error with all of them. So issue is not with the table's name.

Comment: try `composer update`. this type of error generally comes due to broken dependency. so `composer update` would likely fix it.

Comment: Already updated.

Comment: What happens if you run the migration without `--create` option?

Comment: Getting same error even after running without `--create` .